# make it InfiniteScroll

Tags: jquery, laravel

```
public function loadMore()
    {
       
        $this->paginateVar= $this->paginateVar+7;
        $this->messages_count= Message::where('conversation_id',$this->selectedConversation->id)->count();
        $this->messages= Message::where('conversation_id', $this->selectedConversation->id)
        ->skip($this->messages_count - $this->paginateVar)
        ->take($this->paginateVar)->get();


        $height=$this->height;
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('updatedHeight',($height));

    }


 window.addEventListener('updatedHeight', event => {
                    
                    let old = event.detail.height;
                    let newHeight = $('.chatbox_body')[0].scrollHeight;
                    $(".chatbox_body").scrollTop(newHeight - old);
                    let height = $(".chatbox_body").scrollTop();
                
                            window.livewire.emit('updateHeight', {
                            height: height,
                    });
                    
                    

                });

public function updateHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height= $height;

    }
```

I've try a lot of method to make it infinite scrolling but i cant
Hope you guys can help me to do this.
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.